# How to know which columns value is different between two rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to compare two addresses from the same ID to see whether they match. For example:

```
Id  Adress Code     Address
1   1               123 Main
1   2               123 Main
2   1               456 Wall
2   2               456 Wall
3   1               789 Right
3   2               100 Left
```

I'm just trying to figure out which column have changed value between two records having same ID. Like in above data ID ( 1, 2 ) have same address but different address code and ID 3 have different Address

**Update**
Expected result should be like this

```
Id   ColumnChanged
1    AddressCode
2    AddressCode
3    Address
```

Comment: In order to better understand. Can you give to us the expected result from the data you supply?

Comment: And if two records from the same id differ in more than one column?

Comment: If fact from your sample data for id = 3 the value of Columns Changed could be AddessCode too.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I propose, If you have more columns to test differences you just have to union another select in the same manner. 
As I previously commented, in the sample date you provide for id =3 both [Address] and [Address Code] have different values, for these situations two rows are given one showing that column [Address] is different and another showing that column [Address Code] is different.

```
select id, 'Address Code' As [Column Changed] from
(
select distinct id, [Address Code] from Addresses 
) As Differents
group by id
Having count(*) > 1
UNION 
select id, 'Address'  As [Column Changed] from
(
select distinct id, [Address] from Addresses 
) As Differents
group by id
Having count(*) > 1
```

### Output

```
id  Column Changed
1   Address Code
2   Address Code
3   Address Code
3   Address
```